# Farsi Text Displayed in inverse in phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

i'm very new to phpMyAdmin...

whene i try to type farsi (persian) in SQL tab in phpMyadmin its display in inverse

let me tell you my problem with an example:
i open localhost/phpmyadmin then go to SQL tab and want to type this code:

```
INSERT INTO myDatabaseName.myTable
VALUES (
'دیتابیس من'
);
```

but its display like that:

```
INSERT INTO myDatabaseName.myTable
VALUES (
'سیباتید نم'
);
```

[image: image for better understanding]

but this problem only for SQL tab because whene i use wizard to insert record to my table or anything else the farsi text shows correctly...

Apologies for the bad English explanation

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.